# React Native undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.toggleDrawer')

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and so I'm wondering why I'm receiving an error like
"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.toggleDrawer')" when I try to click on hamburger menu in my Home

Here below my Home.js

```js
const NavigatorHome  = props => {
  return (
    <View>
    <AppHeader navigation={props.navigation} title="Home" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default class Home extends Component {
  
  state = {
    users: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const users = await ajax.fetchUsers();
    //ET20200226 This was a warning
    this.setState({users});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <NavigatorHome></NavigatorHome>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.h2text}>
          List of requests
        </Text>
          <FlatList
          data={this.state.users}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
          <View style={styles.flatview}>
            <Text style={styles.uuid}>{item.uuid}</Text>
          </View>
          }
          keyExtractor={item => item.uuid}
        />
      </View>
      </View>    
    );
  }
}
```

Here my AppHeader.js

```js
const AppHeader = props => {  
   return (
    <Header
      //leftComponent={<HamburgerMenu navigation={props.navigation} />}
      leftComponent={<Icon
      color="#fff"
      name="menu"
      onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
    />}
      centerComponent={{
        text: props.title,
        style: { color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }
      }}
      statusBarProps={{ barStyle: "light-content" }}
    />
  );
};

export default AppHeader;
```

Can someone help me to figure out how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please tell us which navigation library you are using?

Comment: React-navigation

Comment: But, you have not added code where you have created your navigator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `props.navigation` is undefined in `NavigatorHome`. you must pass `props.navigation` to `NavigatorHome`. Your code should be as follows:

```js
<View>
   <NavigatorHome navigation={this.props.navigation}></NavigatorHome>
<View>
```